# Need help with touch gestures on an html website

Tags: html, touch, gestures

I am currently working on a web application. I have a menu bar that moves when someone clicks on arrow. With every click a new menu option is activated.

Now, I would like to give the user the option to slide over the menu bar/screen to navigate on a touch interface.

Any idea how I would do that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I don't think you'll be able to do it using *just* HTML, but if you're comfortable with jQuery take a look at this:

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/swipe

This plugin enables you to bind events to gestures, but I believe it only works on iPhone and iPad.